# GLSL Shader - Coverflow Reflection of a 2D object

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I want to write a shader that creates a reflection of an image similiar to the ones used for coverflows.

```
// Vertex Shader
uniform highp mat4 u_modelViewMatrix;
uniform highp mat4 u_projectionMatrix;
attribute highp vec4 a_position;
attribute lowp vec4 a_color;
attribute highp vec2 a_texcoord;
varying lowp vec4 v_color;
varying highp vec2 v_texCoord;
mat4 rot = mat4( -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                  0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
void main()
{
  gl_Position = (u_projectionMatrix * u_modelViewMatrix) * a_position * rot;
  v_color = a_color;
  v_texCoord = a_texcoord;
}

// Fragment Shader
varying highp vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture0;
uniform int slices;
void main()
{
  lowp vec3 w = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);
  lowp vec3 b = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
  lowp vec3 mix = mix(b, w, (v_texCoord.y-(float(slices)/10.0)));
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture0,v_texCoord) * vec4(mix, 1.0);
}
```

But this shader is creating the following:
[current result](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/207/testvw.png/)
And I dont know how to "flip" the image horizontally and I tried so many different parameters in the rotation matrix (I even tried to use a so called "mirror matrix") but I dont know how to reflect the image on the bottom of original image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about what images.google.com returns for "coverflow" result, then you don't need rotation matrix at all.

```
void main()
{
  gl_Position = (u_projectionMatrix * u_modelViewMatrix) * a_position;
  v_color = a_color;
  v_texCoord = vec2(a_texcoord.x, 1.0 - a_texcoord.y);
}
```

Simply flip it vertically.

If you insist on using matrix and want to make a "mirror" shader (the one that takes it object, and puts it under "floor" to make reflection) then you need mirror matrix (don't forget to adjust frontface/backface culling):

```
mat4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
```

AND you must know where the floor is.

```
gl_Position = (u_projectionMatrix * u_modelViewMatrix) * (a_position * mirrorMatrix - floor);
```

Alternatively you could put floor translation into same matrix. Basically, to mirror against arbitrary height, you need to combine three transforms (pseudocode).

`translate(0, -floorHeight, 0) * scale(1, -1, 1) * translate(0, floorHeight, 0)`.

and put them into your matrix.

Also it might make sense to split modelView matrix into "model"(object/world) and "view" matrices. This way it'll be easier to perform transformations like these.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I just have to figure out how to make a transparent gradient so I can use any color not only black to fade out :) ... is there an easy way to move the image down on the y-axis about its own height?